# HTTP Post completely exiting thread, no exception caught, or hangs forever

Tags: java, android

I knew my code was dying somehow because of the other symptoms, but even though I had try/catch around everything, there was never any message.  I've now finally narrowed it down by use of successive output statements.

```
    String line = null;
    try {
        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);    
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        postDebugMessage("GlobalApplication", "Info", "Executing httppost");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        postDebugMessage("GlobalApplication", "Info", "Getting entity");
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        postDebugMessage("GlobalApplication", "Info", "Converting to line");
        line = EntityUtils.toString(entity);   //<- the bad one
        postDebugMessage("GlobalApplication", "Info", "Conversion completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Any error occurring here we're going to state is
        // a network error.
        postDebugMessage("GlobalApplication", "Exception", ex.getStackTrace()[0].toString());
        throw new NetworkNotAvailableException(ex.toString());

    }
```

Based on my debug output statements, the line = EntityUtils.toString(entity) never completes, and no statement after that in the entire service thread executes...the whole thing just vanishes.

I know that EntityUtils.toString() can throw 2 exceptions, an IOException and a ParseException, and I'm going to try and add those next, but shouldn't an overall Exception catch it?

Comment: Yes, the overall Exception catches it, so that is not the problem.

Comment: yep both extend java.lang.Exception and are catched by the try/catch block. Whats your url? and what should the response look like? can you ensure that the server responses what you expect?

Comment: I do actions on "line" further along.  I now do an explicit check to see if line came out null from the EntityUtils.toString() call.  I actually have those line operations surround by a try/catch (Exception), so I would think an NPE would also be caught later on.

Comment: I just ran it again, and this time the output statements indicate it stopped running immediately after "Executing Httppost".  From that point on there are no more debug statements.  I guess it could either be exiting the thread completely, or simply hanging forever.  All of my problems seem to be within the try block above, but no one particular place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to call this answered, because I've solved my problem it appears, but it wasn't related to the EntityUtils call (at least so far as I can tell).

It was not an exception exiting the thread completely, it was just a hung thread.  The culprit was that I had put in a connection timeout, but not a socket connection timeout.  The docs say that the default value is an infinite timeout...and that's what I was seeing I'd say.  I added:

```
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
```

And haven't seen the issue since.

I know at least one log I had showed the entityUtils call never finishing, so that's what led me to think it was that, but more logs after that showed it was the .execute(httpPost) that never completed, so that's what made me look there.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. I suspect that you might be getting an unchecked exception that extends Error rather than Exception. Try putting catch( Throwable t) and see if it catches it. You probably dont want to be actually catching these exceptions, as the state of the system afterwards could be unpredictable if its say an out of memory exception.

Comment: He would then get a crash report.

Comment: I get no crash report of any kind, and the app doesn't FC..it continues on like normal.  I'll add the catch(Throwable t) just to see what I can get.  This seems to be somewhat easily repeatable if I just let the device run long enough, or go into an area with shaky reception.

Comment: I've now added a ton of catches to the whole thing. It ran for a long time in a bad environment, and so far, it has not failed like it did before.  The predominant exception I'm seeing is the IOException, where the operation timed out.  I'm not getting any generic throwable exceptions.  I'll continue to monitor it, but if it works "flawlessly" from now, then it would seem that the IOException somehow was not getting caught as a general exception.  Or was hanging infinitely?  I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityUtils.toString(entity)` first reads some data, and then it does this:

```
char[] tmp = new char[1024];
int l;
while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
   buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
}
```

So the method will block as long as the server is sending more data. I hope that you haven't connected to a streaming service?

Comment: No, the http Response is a single XML file.